# Creating not accessible files on user disc

Tags: security, amazon-s3, architecture

I'm thinking about my new application architecture and in my head I came across a question which I am not able to answer myself.

So my native app written in electron (javascript) will be creating a video file which then will be saved on user disc.

Then from Electron app I'll call rest API written in PHP (which will be responsible only for electron app) which will make call to another rest API written by other developer in Ruby on Rails to gather temporary Amazon s3 access key.

After I get temporary key to Amazon s3 on success I'll start uploading video file **from user disc** to Amazon s3.

Beetwen saving file on user disc and starting upload user can replace/modify file and this new file would upload to s3, I want to secure it from it.

So options that I see are

1. Before save file to user disc I can do call to PHP rest API in order to collect some encrypted key which would be encrypt basing on secret server key* and then this encrypted key would be somehow assigned to video file and then decrypted and checked after upload but before sending video link from Amazon to ror backend. However it can be hackable for user if he find out how to hull/get this encrypted code from video file and assign it to new earlier prepared video file or, even worse, create software doing that automatically.
2. Not to save video on user disc at all but immiedietaly start uploading file to s3 however I don't want app to crash when for example user will be disconnected from network for a second or two on random reason.
3. I can try to create secure folder on user disc which will be not accessible for user and there save all video files but I don't think it's possible to create really secure folder on user disc.

None of these ideas is really save in my opinion,is there some other way to achieve what I want which I don't see?

*that's basically why I need this PHP backend because I don't want to attach too many tasks for ror developer, I want do it myself)

Comment: Nope, there's basically no way to prevent the user from uploading arbitrary data to your S3. Any halfway determined adversarial user would be able to do so. Trying to hide data on the user's own machine won't do anything. The user can always simply intercept the HTTP request to get the raw credentials, then upload anything using any tool they wish.

Comment: So basically second option is the only way to make it secure or I'm wrong again? I would have BLOB representing video inside electron code on user machine and immediately after stop recording send it to PHP backend, without saving BLOB as video on user machine and take care about CORS to make sure data is send from my application not prepared http request from CURL or postman for example. Additionally I would need to handle network connection issue somehow. How ever, would user be able to modify or replace BLOB somehow before sending it to PHP backend?

Comment: Still the same issue. The user will merely have to construct the same kind of HTTP request using any tool they wish. This is not about where your app reads the data from, it’s about being able to spoof the HTTP request using arbitrary tools and sending arbitrary data. Because it’s just an HTTP request. There’s very little protection from that. You’d need your server to verify the uploaded data; e.g. you could verify that it’s a video file, but whether it’s a file created by your app or not is rather hard to verify most likely.

Comment: First of all thank you for your effort, I really appreciate that. I understand that CORS will not help here because   desktop app is not hosted by server -  it is local. Maybe we can implement something like real-time screen sharing from this electron app to some virtual machine which would record it then we would know for sure that recording is legit. However it doesn't prevent user from recording screen previously and just playing already created video on realtime sharing which would look normal. What do you think about checking MD5 just after finish recording and after uploaded to s3?

Comment: What exactly is it you’re trying to prevent here, in a *business* sense?

Comment: Recorded user screen is proof of doing some action on user machine and for accomplish doing something are real money involved. One of my friends suggested on checking MD5 sum just after video is recorded and after uploaded to backend but we are not sure about it. We don't know if MD5 will change when uploading, we only know for sure that MD5 changes when file is modified even one byte.

Comment: I don’t think a video recording will help to prove anything really, and I certainly wouldn’t *depend* on it if it’s about real money. Especially when real money is involved, there’s a great incentive to become creative and circumvent any and all of your measures.

Comment: It's just one of many proofs we don't rely only on it. Anyway with your help we come to conclusion that it's impossible to make videos 100% secure.